# Map level inconsistencies with Missing values

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset, associations, map, missing

Negative `Level` specs interact with `Missing` values, eg:

```
ds = <|"a" -> {1, 2, 3}, "b" -> {4, Missing[], 6}|>
```

Then

```
ds // Map[Framed, #, {-2}] &
```

[image]

And not just in `Association`:

```
ds // Normal // Map[Framed, #, {-2}] &
```

[image]

Similar problem at leaf level:

```
ds // Map[Framed, #, {-1}] &
```

[image]

Whereas positive level spec works, but not good enough for reverse indexing:

```
ds // Normal // Map[Framed, #, {1}] &
```

[image]

Also, `Dataset` both + and - levels fail cryptically with `Association`, eg:

```
Dataset[ds][ Map[Framed, #, {1}] &]
```

> Failure[Dataset,{MessageTemplate:>Dataset::invalid,MessageParameters-><|Head->Map,Arguments->{Framed,Struct({a,b},{Vector(Atom(Integer),3),Vector(Atom(Integer),3)}),{1}},Symbol->Map|>}]

It partially works, eg ok w/ lists and + level specs:

```
Dataset[ds][Normal][ Map[Framed, #, {1}] &] // Normal
```

But similar problems as at the top for lists and - specs:

```
Dataset[ds][Normal][ Map[Framed, #, {-2}] &] // Normal
```

Any partial solutions eg `Missing` `Options`?

Comment: The easiest solution will be to replace `Missing[]` with something atomic like `Indeterminate` or `"missing"`. Fundamentally `Missing[]` has a depth of 2 and you are getting the expected result.

Comment: It looks like `Map` is doing what it's supposed to do (not entirely certain about that `Failure[...]` though).

Comment: @SimonWoods,  ~1500 days --> 2020, by then there'll be an `Option` to make `Missing` atomic to the rest of the language?.. Or at least for `Map`